# In sqlite, how do I use trigger to write to other files?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, auditing

according to [this trigger example](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-triggers.php)

I can use trigger to write to other files for audting trails. How do I exactly do that?

I have tried this to no avail

```
CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER INSERT ON my_table
BEGIN
ATTACH DATABASE /location/otherfile AS logDb
Insert ..
```

I tried the above code the sqlite console and got the syntax error near ATTACH. How else can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inside a trigger body, only INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/SELECT statements are allowed, and you cannot access other database schemas.

To access other files, you have to create a user-defined function, which requires support from any application that modifies the database.